# automatically add changes to local repository from local folder

Tags: git

I want to sync changes which are being made in local folder to be added automatically in local repository.
So, that I don't need to add changes manually every time into local repository before committing changes.

Local Repository path : /home/GIT/local_repository

Local folder path : /home/tool/local_folder

If i made changes in local_folder then those changes automatically added to local_repository without adding manually.

Comment: and why the local folder is not in your repository then?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the git hooks in this case. post_commit will be helpful.  https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_commit

You can add a script in .git/hooks/post-commit that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
git push origin master
```

Considering `/home/tool/local_folder` is cloned from `/home/GIT/local_repository`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you only needs to have two synced directories despite version controlling in between.

**Rsync** would be ideal for that. Please refer -  [link](https://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/)

Comment: Will it work if local folder paths are different but local repository is at same path on all servers?

Comment: Yes it's possible. 
Example - rsync -avzh /root/rpmpkgs /tmp/backups/
You can create a cron job (crontab) to automate the command so that two directories will sync up periodically.

Answer (score 0):

you can make you new command.

git-commit

```
#! /bin/bash
git add*
git commit -m "$1"
```

and install it on/bin